# How to interprete this sentence? (an einem Glas hängenbleiben.)

Tags: verb, verb-usage

> Gerade als er den Löffel in die Tasche stecken will, bleibt er mit dem Löffel an seinem Glas hängen.

Is it really,

> As he would put the spoon in the bag, he stayed with the spoon around his glas hang.

?

I can't understand the last part. Please someone help me. What does *"bleibt an seinem Glas hängen"* mean?

Comment: meaning 2 here: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/haengen_bleiben

Comment: Note that "gerade als" is not "really as", but rather "just as", "at the exact moment when".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb »(an etwas) *[hängenbleiben](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/h%C3%A4ngenbleiben)*« is a [separable verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb) that means »*to get stuck* (at/on something)« or »*to stick* (at/on something)«

In many grammatical situations such verbs are separated, where the former first part moves to the ende of the sentence, while the other part stays at the expected place.

The sentence from your question is in English:

> Just as he wants to put the spoon in his pocket, he sticks to the glass with the spoon.

Comment: I didn't notice it was a separable verb. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In German `an <noun> hängen bleiben` describes a situation where you get or are stuck (replace `<noun>` with a noun). In this sentence it means that *he* tries to put the spoon in his bag but get's stuck with the spoon inside his glas. So now for example it could happen that he accidentally throws his glas on the ground because the spoon is stuck inside.